# Swift 3 UICollectionView Error

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my iOS app, I have a UICollectionView controller with the following code inside:

```
var images = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadImages()
    // Register cell classes
}

func loadImages() {
    images.append(UIImage(named: "ActivityTab")!)
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return images.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! EventCollectionViewCell

    let image = images[indexPath.row]

    cell.imageView.image = image

    return cell
}
```

And I have a UICollectionViewCell (EventCollectionViewCell) with the following code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.imageView.image = nil
}
```

I have linked everything up with the storyboard too. This looks like it should work but I get the following error:

> Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x1092c04a8) to EventCollectionViewCell'

Does anyone know what the error is and how to fix it. It only shows when I return images.count in the number of sections.

I am using xcode 9 but have tried with xcode 8 and the error still persists. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: `loadImages(){ is // Register cell classes}` Did you correctly register the `EventCollectionViewCell` there?

Answer (score 0):

Let change this line of code:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! EventCollectionViewCell
```

to:

```
guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? EventCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
```

Comment: I tried this but got a different error: _he cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:'_

Comment: I need to see your code to register cell classes, what is the full code?

Comment: import UIKit

class EventCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.imageView.image = nil
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Check for the following things:

1. `EventCollectionViewCell` is a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`.
2. Have you registered `EventCollectionViewCell` with the `collectionView`?
3. `EventCollectionViewCell` has the same `Reusable Identifier` that you are using while calling `dequeueReusableCell` with "`reuseIdentifier`".

What is the value of `reuseIdentifier` here?

Comment: I have checked all those things and reuseidentifier has the value of 'Cell' which is what is in my cell on the storyboard too